# Python exclude non accessible image with requests

Tags: python-3.x, django, image, python-requests, google-custom-search

I've written a really simple function with requests, which with a giver URL checks if it gets a response and if this response is an image. It actually works, but is crazy slow at times. I'm too
inexperienced to understand why is that. How can I improve it or achieve the same thing in a better and faster way?

```
def is_image_url(url):

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        status = response.status_code
        print(status)
    
        if response.status_code == 200:
            content_type = response.headers.get('content-type')
            print(content_type)
            if content_type.startswith('image'):
                return True
        return False
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```

I'm using that function to exclude images who are not accessible, like images from Instagram, Facebook etc.
I thought it could work fine because I actually need to check only 10 images that I get from Google custom search API.

for now I've excluded the function from the application, and tried do a similar thing with checking the image height or width to assure that it existed and was accessible without much success.

### loop i use to call the function

```
for image in img['items']:
                        height = image['image']['height']
                        width = image['image']['width']
                        imgTitle = image['title']
                        imgHtmlTitle = image['htmlTitle']
                        imgContext = image['image']['contextLink']
                        imgLink = image['link']
                        workingImg = is_image_url(imgLink)
                        print(f'alt {height}.... larg {width}')
                        image_info = {'imgTitle' : imgTitle, 'imgHtmlTitle' : imgHtmlTitle, "imgContext" : imgContext, "imgLink" : imgLink}
                        if workingImg:
                           image_results.append(image_info)
```

Comment: It is just slow because you download the image. You perhaps can use `.head` instead to boost this a bit, but the main factor why it slows down is because of the request.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've tried `.head`and as you said it made it faster, do you know a better way to get a similar result?

Comment: @jkzz: well the problem is that you make a HTTP request, and thus have to wait for the response. Most of the time is thus *waiting* for a response, and not 10% of the time, but likely ~99% of the time. So likely making the request parallel will help.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem: sorry as i said i'm inexperienced i understand that waiting for the response can take a while, what do you mean by making the request parallel?

Comment: yes, you can not do much about determining if *one* element is an image, but if you need to test it for let's say ten items, you can check these in parallel. Very likely the speedup is *almost* tenfold.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem i see, so instead of calling the function with a loop for every image url in the list, i could make all the requests at the same time?

Comment: yes, can you perhaps share the code that is used to determine this for *multipel* objects, so the loop you wrote?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem yes of course, i've posted the loop which calls the function.